How to Receive SMS in Node.js/Express from ESP32 with SIM800L?
I'm working on a project where I need to receive SMS messages sent from an ESP32 device equipped with a SIM800L module. The SIM800L is using a personal SIM card with its own number.
I’m currently using Node.js with Express.js for my backend. Can anyone help me? I’m looking for a way to receive these SMS messages directly without relying on another esp32, third-party apps, or services like Twilio or any other services.
THANKSS IN ADVANCE!!
I tried using third-party apps, but I don’t want to rely on them because it creates extra hassle for users to use those apps before they can receive sms on my application.

the SIM800L allows you to connect to the internet (GPRS) - use that, SMS will need some device with another SIM, or a third-party service, or perhaps a phone connected to some computer

You can even use a service like https://www.twilio.com/en-us/messaging/channels/sms.
The arduino program to send a message is similar to this:
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>

const char* ssid = "YOUR_WIFI_SSID";
const char* password = "YOUR_WIFI_PASSWORD";
const char* serverUrl = "http://yourbackend.com/sms";

SoftwareSerial sim800(27, 26); // RX, TX pins for ESP32

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  sim800.begin(9600);
  
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi...");
  }
  Serial.println("Connected to WiFi");

  // Set SMS mode to text
  sim800.println("AT+CMGF=1");
  delay(100);
}

void loop() {
  if (sim800.available()) {
    String smsContent = sim800.readString();
    
    // Check if the message is an incoming SMS
    if (smsContent.indexOf("+CMT:") != -1) {
      sendSmsToBackend(smsContent);
    }
  }
}

void sendSmsToBackend(String smsContent) {
  HTTPClient http;
  http.begin(serverUrl);
  http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  
  // Create JSON payload
  String payload = "{\"message\": \"" + smsContent + "\"}";
  int httpResponseCode = http.POST(payload);
  
  if (httpResponseCode > 0) {
    String response = http.getString();
    Serial.println(response);
  } else {
    Serial.println("Error sending SMS to backend");
  }

  http.end();
}

The backend should look like this:
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.post('/sms', (req, res) => {
  const { message } = req.body;
  
  console.log("Received SMS:", message);

  // Process the SMS content here
  res.sendStatus(200);
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server running on port 3000'));


You can even keep the sendSmsToBackend function in setup to avoid loop of messages.


"without relying on another esp32, third-party apps, or services like Twilio" ... so your answer is "use Twilio" ... nice
